# AttributeError: 'BotClient' object has no attribute 'loop' with declaring an instance

Tags: python, class, oop, discord, bots

Trying to write a Discord Bot in Python, although having trouble. Currently receiving the error "AttributeError: 'BotClient' object has no attribute 'loop'". I've looked this up before posting, and it seems to be because of not declaring an instance of the class, however I am (see last two lines of code)... Unless something else is incorrect?

Current code is as follows:

```
class BotClient(discord.Client):

def __init__(self, prefix, current_game):
    self.pfx = prefix
    self.curr_game = current_game

async def on_ready(self):
    print(f'{self.user} has connected to Discord!')
    await self.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=self.curr_game)

#@self.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('%s hello' % self.pfx):
        await message.channel.send('very naisu caesar-chan')

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
CHANNEL = os.getenv('CHANNEL_TOKEN')
CUR_GAME = os.getenv('GAME_ENV')

RockBot = BotClient(".rb", CUR_GAME)
RockBot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the `__init__()` function that extends to the class `discord.Client`. Apparently, you need to initialize the `__init()__` inside the class `discord.Client` because your new init function overwrote the discord's init function (aka the super class init function). And this should be fairly simple to fix. Just initialize it inside your new init function:

```py
class BotClient(discord.Client):

    def __init__(self, prefix, current_game, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pfx = prefix
        self.curr_game = current_game
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.user} has connected to Discord!')
        await self.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=self.curr_game)
    
    #@self.event
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
    
        if message.content.startswith('%s hello' % self.pfx):
            await message.channel.send('very naisu caesar-chan')

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
CHANNEL = os.getenv('CHANNEL_TOKEN')
CUR_GAME = os.getenv('GAME_ENV')

RockBot = BotClient(".rb", CUR_GAME)
RockBot.run(TOKEN)
```