# Discord.py: How do I write discord bot in OOP without using Cogs? I have an error while I tried it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been working on discord bot for a pretty long time and now I decided that it is time that I start using the Bot with OOP as I am getting into it. I have given it a simple try and tried to run it but it was showing some error which I didn't understand.

When I use the following code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class JervisI(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, command_prefix, case_insensitive, botintents):
        self.command_prefix = command_prefix
        self.case_insensitive = case_insensitive
        self.botintents = botintents


J1 = JervisI(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True, botintents=discord.Intents.all())
J1.run("---HIDDEN TOKEN---")
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Bhavyadeep\Desktop\Discord Bot (Python)\PHub-Bot-1\jervis-1.py", line 12, in <module>
    J1.run("---HIDDEN TOKEN---")
  File "c:\Users\Bhavyadeep\Desktop\Discord Bot (Python)\PHub-Bot-1\The-Naval-Historian\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 692, in run
    loop = self.loop
AttributeError: 'JervisI' object has no attribute 'loop'
```

I have no idea on how to do it. Please do let me know where the error is.

Thank You! :D

Comment: Is the following post helping you? [AttributeError: 'BotClient' object has no attribute 'loop'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67513696/attributeerror-botclient-object-has-no-attribute-loop-with-declaring-an-ins)

Comment: No @Dominik! My bot works on `Command API` of the library and not the client.

Comment: Well, it indeed lookes like you are modifying the `__init__()` function. Why are you talking about `Command API`, what is that? You mean you want to use `commands.command()`?

Comment: @Dominik Yeah. Exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the `__init__` method of `commands.Bot`, if you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L102-L127) you can see that it's pretty long and important, you're gonna get a ton of `AttributeError`s if you don't call the "original" `__init__` method:

```py
class JervisI(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, command_prefix, case_insensitive, botintents):
        super().__init__( # Same arguments that you pass to `commands.Bot(...)`
            command_prefix=command_prefix, 
            case_insensitive=case_insensitive,
            intents=botintents
        )

        self.command_prefix = command_prefix # You don't need to create this, it already exists
        self.case_insensitive = case_insensitive
        self.botintents = botintents
```

Comment: Hey, can you change the answer if I change my question? I want to work with Cogs now. This question might get me banned from asking questions.

Comment: Yeah I will add you. Anyways, I think I will delete this question? I really don't want to be blocked and try to post some productive question.

Comment: It’s a productive question, also you can’t really delete the question when there’s an answer already, feel free to accept it

Comment: Yeah. But that (-1) rating though!